# Cross-platform way to remove dir from tarball

Tags: macos, unix, tar

I found this:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-appleosx-bsd-tar-remove-directory/

```
tar --delete -f file.tar 'path1/dir1'
```

but this does not work on MacOS. I get:

> `tar: Option --delete is not supported`

I am looking for something that works on all *nix flavors. Anybody know a good way to do this? Maybe I really do need to extract first and ignore the folder and then re-tarball it?

Comment: Basically, `tar` is not `zip` (for example, tar files don't have a central directory, instead every file stored in the archive is preceded with the meta-data), so it cannot effectively be used as a virtual file-system like a zip-file (ie replaceing/deleting files in the archive -- append is okay though). True, some tar-versions do their best to provide/emulate such features, but it is neither portable nor efficient; if you wish zip-like features just use zip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Yes, if you want a solution that works on many **nix flavours* then you're going to have to; extract first, ignore the folder, and then re-tarball it.

---

#### Solution:

I would do something like the following:

```bash
# Path to source .tar
src_tar=/the/path/to/your/tarfile.tar

# Path to dir in .tar that you want to delete.
rm_tar_dir=path1/dir1

# Create a temporary dir for extracting the .tar contents into.
tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d 2>/dev/null || mktemp -d -t 'tar-tmpdir')

# Extract all contents from the source .tar to a temporary dir
tar zxf "$src_tar" -C "$tmp_dir"

# Delete the unwanted dir from temporary dir.
rm -rf "${tmp_dir:?}/${rm_tar_dir}"

# Create new .tar archive, overwriting the original source .tar
tar czf "$src_tar" -C "$tmp_dir" .

# Clean up
rm -rf "$tmp_dir"
```

---

#### Why do I recommend the solution shown above:

Firstly, (for hopefully obvious reasons) it's beyond my capacity to be able to test and confirm that the solution above works successfully across all **nix flavours*. Secondly, it would be naive of me to say otherwise because, (as I'm sure you're aware), it's a big old landscape out there, i.e. there's many versions, flavours, and variants.

I have concluded upon the solution suggested above based on the following findings/research. The flavours of **nix* covered in the support/compatibility tables below are far from exhaustive. I've selected them from the flavours listed [here](http://www.linfo.org/flavors.html).

A majority of the chosen *flavours* are those that are developed by groups of volunteers who make them available for free (Open BSD, Free BSD, etc). Fortunately documentation, man-pages, etc for these **nix flavours* are published online and they have been the main influence in my decision making.  IBM AIX, and Sun's Solaris being the exceptions as they're proprietary, however some docs, man-pages, etc were available for those two.

---

#### Support/Compatibility Tables

- **The `tar --delete` option**

  Let's begin by looking at support for the `tar` commands `--delete` option. As you can see in the table below, it's far from widely supported `:(` Hence why it seems necessary to take the more verbose solution - unfortunately we can't utilize a oneliner when cross-platform is a requirement.

  ```
                ┌─────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────────────┬───────┬─────────┐
                │ IBM │ Open │ Free │ Net │ Darwin/MacOS │ Linux │ Sun     │
                │ AIX │ BSD  │ BSD  │ BSD │     BSD      │  GNU  │ Solaris │
  ┌─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │ --delete    │  x  │  x   │  x   │  √  │       x      │   √   │    x    │
  └─────────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
  ```
- **Other `tar` options**

  The solution provided above utilizes several of the `tar` options, namely; `-z`, `-x`, `-f`, `-c`, and `-C`. As you can see in the table below they are widely supported. However, notably the `-z` option, (which is used to filter the archive through gzip), is not supported on IBM's AIX which to my understanding is used on mainframes - (so, my assumption is that's probably not to much of a dealbreaker for you).

  ```
                ┌─────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────────────┬───────┬─────────┐
                │ IBM │ Open │ Free │ Net │ Darwin/MacOS │ Linux │ Sun     │
                │ AIX │ BSD  │ BSD  │ BSD │     BSD      │  GNU  │ Solaris │
  ┌─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  -z         │  x  │  √   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  -x         │  √  │  √   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  -f         │  √  │  √   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  -c         │  √  │  √   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  -C         │  √  │  √   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  --exclude  │  x  │  x   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    x    │
  └─────────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
  ```

  **The `tar --exclude` option**

  Note in the previous table the `--exclude` option doesn't appear to be widely supported too - for this reason we don't use it in the suggested solution. I would avoid opting to exclude the unwanted directory (i.e. the one you want to delete) when unpacking the `.tar`. So avoid doing something like this:

  ```bash
  # Don't do this....

  # Extract all contents from the source .tar to a temporary dir,
  # and exclude the directory that you effectively want to delete.
  tar zxf "path/to/tarfile.tar" --exclude "path1/dir1" -C "path/to/tmpdir"
  ```

  You'll notice in the suggested solution we unpack all the contents (without exclusion), then remove the unwanted directory using `rm -rf`, before repacking it.

---

- **Other commands the solution utilizes**

  The table below shows the remaining commands utilized in the suggested solution:

  ```
                ┌─────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────────────┬───────┬─────────┐
                │ IBM │ Open │ Free │ Net │ Darwin/MacOS │ Linux │ Sun     │
                │ AIX │ BSD  │ BSD  │ BSD │     BSD      │  GNU  │ Solaris │
  ┌─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  rm -rf     │  √  │  √   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  mktemp     │  x  │  √   │  ?   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  mktemp -d  │  x  │  √   │  ?   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  ├─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  mktemp -t  │  x  │  √   │  ?   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  └─────────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
  ```

  As you can see, we're good to utilize `rm -rf` as it's well supported.

  **Be cautious of `mktemp`...**

  `mktemp` and it's `-t` and `-d` option seems to be less widely supported. (Note: I'm unsure whether it is or isn't supported on Free BSD - hence the `?` indicator).

  So, whilst my suggested solution does utilize `mktemp`, you may want to use `mkdir -p` instead, as that's widely supported as shown in the following table:

  ```
                ┌─────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────────────┬───────┬─────────┐
                │ IBM │ Open │ Free │ Net │ Darwin/MacOS │ Linux │ Sun     │
                │ AIX │ BSD  │ BSD  │ BSD │     BSD      │  GNU  │ Solaris │
  ┌─────────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
  │  mkdir -p   │  √  │  √   │  √   │  √  │      √       │   √   │    √    │
  └─────────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
  ```

---

#### References

The following references were used to conclude on the suggested solution, and compile the compatibility tables:

1. **`tar`**

   - [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/tar.htm)
   - [Open BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/tar)
   - [Free BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=&n=1)
   - [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?tar+1+NetBSD-1.6)
   - [Darwin/MacOS BSD](https://ss64.com/osx/tar.html)
   - [Linux](https://ss64.com/bash/tar.html)
   - [Sun Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/tar-1.html)
   - [GNU Tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC11)
2. **`mktemp -d -t`**

   - [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/m_nav.htm)
   - [Open BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/mktemp)
   - [Free BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)
   - [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?mktemp+1+NetBSD-1.6)
   - [Darwin/MacOS BSD](https://ss64.com/osx/mktemp.html)
   - [Linux](https://ss64.com/bash/mktemp.html)
   - [Linux manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp)
   - [Sun Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/mktemp-1.html#scrolltoc)
3. **`rm -rf`**

   - [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/rm.htm)
   - [Open BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/rm)
   - [Free BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)
   - [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?rm+1+NetBSD-1.6)
   - [Darwin/MacOS BSD](https://ss64.com/osx/rm.html)
   - [Linux](https://ss64.com/bash/rm.html)
   - [Sun Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/rm-1.html#scrolltoc)
4. **`mkdir -p`**

   - [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/mkdir.htm)
   - [Open BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/mkdir)
   - [Free BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mkdir&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)
   - [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?tar+1+NetBSD-1.6)
   - [Darwin/MacOS BSD](https://ss64.com/osx/mkdir.html)
   - [Linux](https://ss64.com/bash/mkdir.html)
   - [Sun Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/mkdir-1.html#scrolltoc)
5. **Others**

   - [Flavours of UNIX](http://www.linfo.org/flavors.html)
   - [Creating a temporary directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30091/fix-or-alternative-for-mktemp-in-os-x/84980#84980#answer-84980)